# Loading CSV in D3 changes character values

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm uploading a csv file in D3 that has 3 columns: Class, CXX, CYY

```
Class,CXX,CYY
st0,-179.5,1798.1
st0,12.5,1790.1
st0,4.5,1790.1
st0,4.5,1790.1
...
```

The Class has 3 values- st0, st1 or st3, but for some reason when I look at log.console of the loaded file all Class values change to st0 (see the screenshot, the CXX and CYY are normal). Could anyone advise on what is the issue here?

Top left is the file that is being uploaded, on the right is the script and bottom left is the console

[image]

I'm uploading the file using a simple

```
d3.csv("CircleCoordinates.csv", function(data) {
            console.log(data)};
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not in this small test

```js
var dataCSV = `Class,CXX,CYY
st0,-179.5,1798.1
st0,12.5,1790.1
st0,4.5,1790.1
st0,4.5,1790.1
st1,-179.5,1798.1
st1,12.5,1790.1
st1,4.5,1790.1
st1,4.5,1790.1`;

var data = d3.csvParse(dataCSV);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```